# Difficulty inserting nodes to binary search tree using templates and template inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

What I am dealing with is I have created 3 template classes. I am trying to make a library for binary trees though I have limited knowledge of C++. I have implemented binary trees in C using structs but this time I wanted to take advantage of the object oriented programming C++ offers so I created classes for the node, the binary tree and the binary search tree.

I feel more comfortable showing all the code in case there is something else wrong that I didn't notice. So here it is. (Note: C++11 in use)

node_class.h

```
template <typename key_type, typename value_type>
class node_class {
public:
    node_class(key_type key, value_type value) {
        SetKey(key);
        SetValue(value);
        SetLeft(nullptr);
        SetRight(nullptr);
    }
    void SetKey(key_type key) {
        this->key = key;
    }
    void SetValue(value_type value) {
        this->value = value;
    }
    void SetLeft(node_class <key_type, value_type> *left) {
        this->left = left;
    }
    void SetRight(node_class <key_type, value_type> *right) {
        this->right = right;
    }
    key_type GetKey() {
        return this->key;
    }
    value_type GetValue() {
        return this->value;
    }
    node_class <key_type, value_type> *GetLeft() {
        return this->left;
    }
    node_class <key_type, value_type> *GetRight() {
        return this->right;
    }
private:
    key_type key;
    value_type value;
    node_class <key_type, value_type> *left;
    node_class <key_type, value_type> *right;
};
```

binary_tree_class.h

```
template <typename key_type, typename value_type>
class binary_tree_class {
public:
    binary_tree_class() {
        SetRoot(nullptr);
    }
    // ...
protected:
    void SetRoot(node_class <key_type, value_type> *root) {
        this->root = root;
    }
    node_class <key_type, value_type> *GetRoot() {
        return this->root;
    }
private:
    node_class <key_type, value_type> *root;
    // ...
};
```

binary_search_tree_class.h

```
template <typename key_type, typename value_type>
class binary_search_tree_class : public binary_tree_class <key_type, value_type> {
public:
    binary_search_tree_class() {

    }
    void Insert(key_type key, value_type value) {
        Insert(key, value, this->GetRoot());
    }
    void Insert(key_type key, value_type value, node_class <key_type, value_type> *node) {
        if (node == nullptr) {
            node = new node_class <key_type, value_type> (key, value);
        }
        if (key > node->GetKey()) {
            Insert(key, value, node->GetRight());
        } else if (key < node->GetKey()) {
            Insert(key, value, node->GetLeft());
        }
    }
    // ...
};
```

As far as the Insert function is conserned, I read that I have to pass the node parameter by reference to pointer in order for the changes to the tree to take place (Correct me if I am wrong). That being said I have to change the function protorype from this

```
void Insert(key_type key, value_type value, node_class <key_type, value_type> *node)
```

into this

```
void Insert(key_type key, value_type value, node_class <key_type, value_type> *&node)
```

After I did that I was completely unable to figure out what is wrong so I am still stuck with the following error from g++

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
binary_search_tree_class.h: In instantiation of ‘void binary_search_tree_class<key_type, value_type>::Insert(key_type, value_type) [with key_type = int; value_type = int]’:
main.cpp:5:31:   required from here
binary_search_tree_class.h:11:9: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘node_class<int, int>*&’ from an rvalue of type ‘node_class<int, int>*’
   Insert(key, value, this->GetRoot());
         ^
binary_search_tree_class.h:13:7: note:   initializing argument 3 of ‘void binary_search_tree_class<key_type, value_type>::Insert(key_type, value_type, node_class<key_type, value_type>*&) [with key_type = int; value_type = int]’
  void Insert(key_type key, value_type value, node_class <key_type, value_type> *&node) {
```

In the files above I couldn't write the include directives because the # symbol was causing problems with the indentation but I think you get it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)

Comment: @tobi303 I will check this out ;)

Comment: your `GetRoot` returns the pointer by value, ie if you call `this->GetRoot()` you get a temporary that is then passed to `Insert`, even this would work it would not do what you want, because it would only change the value of that temporary pointer, not to the `root` member

Comment: Great effort! OP. Once you've gotten past the compiler error, I **strongly** suggest you send this code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ because there's a ton of things in your code that could use some improvements. Once you do, you may share the link in the comments here.

Comment: you could make a `GetRootRef` that returns a reference to the pointer, or directly make the `root` protected

Comment: @tobi303 Oh I see ... :/ I didn't know that.

Comment: @WhiZTiM :) Thanks for your kind words. I hope I solve this out. Right now I am trying out some things tobi303 said.

Comment: `the # symbol was causing problems with the indentation` - the code formatting works fine, but it didn't work because code blocks (1) need a blank line before them, and (2) need four spaces on the line before them. Try again?

Comment: @WhiZTiM https://github.com/xorz57/forest Here you are!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Issue

The issue starts from the method:

```
node_class<>* binary_search_tree<>::GetRoot();
```

It returns the **copy** pointer of the variable member `root`.

In other words, when you invoke the method `GetRoot()` you obtain the address location of the `root` node, and potentially save that address into another pointer variable.

Just to give you an idea. Let us suppose there is the root node somewhere in the memory:

```
 0x01 [...]
 0x02 [RootNode]
 0x03 [...]
```

Your binary tree will keep the address of the root node and store it in a pointer (which is a variable anyway).

The layout memory will be something like:

```
0x01 [...]
0x02 [RootNode]
0x03 [...]
0x04 [binary_tree::root = 0x02]
```

Let us suppose we invoke in order to take the root address: `GetRoot()` it will actually return the address of `RootNode` and *not* a reference to the member variable `binary_tree:root` which *points* to the `RootNode`.

So when you invoke `GetRoot()` with:

```
void foo() {
  auto p = binary_tree.GetRoot();
}
```

The layout memory will be something like:

```
0x01 [...]
0x02 [RootNode]
0x03 [...]
0x04 [binary_tree::root = 0x02]
0x05 [...]
0x06 [p = 0x2]
```

As you can see in the scheme, `p` is a *copy* of `root` (variable member), but they are, indeed, two *different* pointers which actually point the same location memory.

So if you pass `p` as *reference* to a function which modifies it, then `p` will be modified but not the member variable `::root`.

The scheme and code is quite schematic, but I hope they will help you to understand the situation. `GetNode()` acts like copying the member variables and not returning a reference to it.

Your compile error comes from the fact that you are not actually saving the return *copied* address into another pointer, but directly passing it as argument. Therefore a *temporary expression* is created and passed to method `Insert`. However a temporary expression cannot be identified by a location in the memory and so you cannot take a reference from it, that's why your compiler says to cannot take a reference from a temporary value.

---

## How to fix it?

There are several methods to approach that problem.

My opinion you can change your class design: just make the member variable *protected* in order to be accessed. In that way you can obtain the "real" pointer and not a copying address value.

---

## Simple suggestions

- This may be personal, but I think that the notation with pointer reference is quite unreadable.
  If your function (or method) needs to modify the address of a pointer, just use: `void foo(node_class**)` (pointer to pointer).
- Adding `_class` to each name class is quite redundant and make the code more verbose. A class name should be just `node`.

Comment: First of all thanks for the effort you put to explain the problem to me. As far as the class names are concerned I was using the European Space Agency Standard for C/C++. I understand the problem now but I tried the pointer to pointer solution but I couldn't get the function call correct. Then I proceeded to the second solution you provided so I got rid of the GetRoot() function and changed the root pointer to protected but it didn't work either :/

Comment: @xorz57 You should have `*root` as protected member variable and delete `GetRoot`. In derived method `Insert` you should pass `root` as third argument (the argument still has to be `node_class*&` because you need to change the address of the pointer).